# ¿Cómo presentar widgets en subcategorías?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Tengo un problema a la hora de presentar un filtro de precios en las subcategorias de productos. Por ejemplo:

Tenemos la categoría "Electrodomésticos" y luego dentro de ella están las subcategorías: "Climatización", "Gran Electrodoméstico", etc.

El caso es que yo pongo el Widget de filtrado por precios y me aparece cuando estoy presente en una página de las categorías padre, pero no cuando estoy en una subcategoría.

De todas formas, he podido observar que hay una subcategoría en la que si aparece ese Widget, y no se por donde abordar este problema, puesto que todas las categorías están con la misma configuración, la misma plantilla, etc.
A parte de eso, en la subcategoría en la si que se ve el Widget no presenta los productos como debe, ya que lo tengo en 15 artículos por página y me presenta 13 y dos huecos libres, y hace paginación, mientras que en las que no se ve este Widget, los presenta bien (15 por página y su paginación correspondiente si es necesaria). Es todo bastante raro, o al menos a mi me lo parece.

P.D: Hice una importación de artículos de una tienda anterior. ¿Podría ser esta la causa?

Gracias por la atención prestada, un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Encontré la solución. El caso es que al importar todos los artículos a la tienda nueva, ha habido algún tipo de fallo, o las importaciones no se hacen de una forma completa. Los artículos estaban dentro de sus respectivas categorías pero por la razón que sea no se reconocía como tal. Comencé a volver a actualizar a mano todos los artículos, y parecía que todo iba cogiendo forma, hasta que vi que Woocommerce dentro de /Estado/Herramientas, tiene precisamente eso: una herramienta entre otras llamda "Tablas de búsqueda de productos", con la cual vuelve a generar toda la información de los productos en base a la que existe y con esto, todo empezó a funcionar, y los widgets se mostraban correctamente.